# What events can com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DeckPanel fire?

Tags: java, events, gwt, handler

Perhaps it's lame question but strangely after 30 mins of googling I can't find the answer.

What events can com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DeckPanel fire ? [JavaDoc says](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DeckPanel.html) it implements HasHandlers but it's declared as `void fireEvent(GwtEvent<?> event)`.

How do I know what types it expects so I can catch events by subscribing to them via `DeckPanel.addHandler(H handler, GwtEvent.Type<H> type)` ?

Specifically I want to catch events when DeckPanel.showWidget() is being called.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DeckPanel` doesn't fire any events itself. The `Widget` type implements `addHandler`, primarily for generic DOM event support - there is no built-in event that will be fired when `DeckPanel#showWidget()` is called. You can implement your own though:

```
public class MyDeckPanel extends DeckPanel {
  public HandlerRegistration addShowWidgetHandler(
      ShowWidgetEventHandler handler) {
    return addHandler(handler, ShowWidgetEvent.getType());
  }

  @Override
  public void showWidget(int index) {
    super.showWidget(index);
    fireEvent(new ShowWidgetEvent(index));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DeckPanel` extends `ComplexPanel`, so it only implements `HasAttachHandlers`. So by default you will only receive the `AttachEvent` as it sinks no other events. But as in with any HTML element, you can make it sink any of the native events by using `addDomHandler` and `addBitlessDomHandler`.